# Ms Excel Vlookup and SUMIFS Help required

Tags: date, excel-formula, excel-2010, vlookup, sumifs

I have a table of 2 clients with history of consumption in the given months with start and end date and count of days as well. I am using V Lookup function to look the client # in the provided table and then count the number of days fall in the Date provided on the other Picture(Work Book 2).

I have that client details in Workbook 1 and the desired days in Workbook 2. But I am not getting the right Answer.

For example as seen in workbook 2 we need to calculate the number of days falls in the summer 2015 and Winter 2016.

I have used dated if(), v lookup and Sum Ifs functions but failed to get the right answer.

[image]

Please help me.

Comment: What formula are you using to get the result in the picture example?

Comment: i have used vlookup to look the client# and then sumifs to calculate the days fall into summer.

Comment: are you sure the dates are actually numbers and not strings?  I usually test this with =isnumber(C12) where C12 is a date in question

Comment: Yes they are dates @ForwardEd

Comment: Also when troubleshooting something like this I would recommend starting off with something simple and building up your formulas from there.  So in this case I would try getting my formulas to work from the same sheet as the data.  Then I would try and a different sheet in same workbook, and then I would make the jump to a different work book.  Basically the fewer things that can go wrong the easier it is to figure out what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

OK going to make a few assumptions here.

Data in Workbook1 located in

Sheet1 with header row in row 1 and first client number in A2, last client number in A24.

Calc table in workbook2 in
Sheet1 with header row in row 1 and first client number in A1

```
=sumproduct(('[workbook1.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$2:$A$24=[workbook2]Sheet1!A2)*
            ('[workbook1.xlsx]Sheet1'!$C$2:$C$24>=[workbook2]Sheet1!B2)*
            ('[workbook1.xlsx]Sheet1'!$D$2:$D$24<=[workbook2]Sheet1!C2)*
            ('[workbook1.xlsx]Sheet1'!$F$2:$F$24))
```

strong probability that you will need both workbooks open at the same time.

Comment: one time when I was doing the date comparison I had to change the format of the date cells to general  and then it started working...still have figured out what happened that one time.